# How to set semi-random name for S3 bucket using cloud formation

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I want to create a cloud formation template that creates an S3 bucket with a human readable name, but which can be run many times automatically. 
Below is a bucket with predefined name.

What can I do to make the name contain a human readable portion in addition to a random unique id? Something like: `MyBucket-abcdabcd`, `MyBucket-efghefgh`, `MyBucket-ijklijkl`.

```
"S3Bucket" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::S3::Bucket",
  "Properties" : {
    "BucketName": "MyBucket",
    "PublicAccessBlockConfiguration" : {
      "BlockPublicAcls" : true,
      "BlockPublicPolicy" : true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: CloudFormation supports Lambda-powered macros that would work for your use case. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cloudformation-macros/

Comment: I guess if there is nothing built in, this could be the answer.

Comment: I don't want to put this as an answer, but maybe a templating engine like jinja2 could make your life way easier when used with YAML templates!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks [Sleeper Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56336349/6739945). This is a great answer and i have been looking for a solution to this for awhile!

---

**tl;dr**

yaml CloudFormation below returns **"bucket-with-semi-random-name-51af3dc0"**

```
BucketWithSemiRandomName:
  Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
  Properties:
    BucketName: !Join
      - "-"
      - - "bucket-with-semi-random-name"
        - !Select
          - 0
          - !Split
            - "-"
            - !Select
              - 2
              - !Split
                - "/"
                - !Ref "AWS::StackId"
```

---

Slight index error in the code sample [provided Sleeper Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56336349/6739945). You will need to replace the select index as below.

Using the same example Stack ARN as original answer...

```
arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:123456789012:stack/teststack/51af3dc0-da77-11e4-872e-1234567db123
```

```
!Select [2, !Split [/, !Ref AWS::StackId ]]
```

Above code sample returns UUID (index 2) from Stack ARN "51af3dc0-da77-11e4-872e-1234567db123"

```
!Select [0, !Split[-, !Select [2, !Split [/, !Ref AWS::StackId ]]]]
```

Above code sample returns first segment (index 0) of UUID from Stack ARN "51af3dc0"

---

This is the resulting yaml that i am now using based on [Sleeper Smith's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56336349/6739945) answer. I've combined a !Join to provide more context to the bucket name.

```
BucketWithSemiRandomName:
  Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
  Properties:
    BucketName: !Join
      - "-"
      - - "bucket-with-semi-random-name"
        - !Select
          - 0
          - !Split
            - "-"
            - !Select
              - 2
              - !Split
                - "/"
                - !Ref "AWS::StackId"
```

Above code sample returns "bucket-with-semi-random-name-51af3dc0"

Comment: Rofl, the 3rd of the 2 hardest computer problem, off by 1 error. Thanks for a more comprehensive and correct answer.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 8):

You have two options.

First option - you can just leave your BucketName property blank. When you leave it blank, it'll yield a name of:
<stackname>-<template logical name>-<random suffix>

So, if you have stack name and template logical name that make sense, it should give you a unique bucket name every time.

Second option - use the Stack ARN suffix, which is a random guid:
arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:123456789012:stack/teststack/51af3dc0-da77-11e4-872e-1234567db123

```
!Select [2, !Split [/, !Ref AWS::StackId ]]
```

That would yield you '51af3dc0-da77-11e4-872e-1234567db123'
You can further split that again and select a portion if you want.

```
!Select [0, !Split[-, !Select [2, !Split [/, !Ref AWS::StackId ]]]]
```

Gives you 51af3dc0

Answer (score 2):

Thanks [Phillip Mattheson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56728927) and [Sleeper Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56336349/981599) for your excellent answers! I wanted to provide an alternative (and somewhat easier to read IMHO) method for producing the same results.  I prefer to use `!Sub` over `!Join` whenever possible (see [this great blog post](https://theburningmonk.com/2019/05/cloudformation-protip-use-fnsub-instead-of-fnjoin/) for more info):

```yaml
  BucketWithSemiRandomName:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName:
        !Sub
          - 'bucket-with-semi-random-name-${RandomGUID}'
          - { RandomGUID: !Select [0, !Split ["-", !Select [2, !Split ["/", !Ref AWS::StackId ]]]] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be:

```
Resources:
    MyBucket:
      Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
Outputs:
  S3Bucket2:
    Description: "My Bucket" 
    Value: !Ref 'MyBucket'
```

Comment: This method will create fully random s3 bucket name not semi random